# Help in using SEO Plugins: SEO Ultimate And Yoast SEO Plugin

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

*I've deleted my previous question as it was migrated from Prowebmaster to WordPress section, and hence it was deep down somewhere.*

I'm in a quandary about using SEO Plugin for my WordPress site. Here's the thing: I was a happy camper with the Yoast SEO Plugin but because I couldn't edit Meta Description in bulk, [I reached out for help in this forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17232/using-excerpts-as-meta-descriptions).

One of the nicest guy recommended me to use SEO Ultimate Plugin. To me, this plugin works very well. Plugin is excellent. Plus, more importantly, I can edit Meta Description without sweating bullets.

Now, Yoast SEO Plugin is configured such that it strips category URLs, modifies archive pages with the /date extension and so on. Also it strips away a lot of unnecessary codes from the WordPress core structure -- the WP version, Rel Next, Prev links, etc.

SEO Ultimate, on the other hand, will be used primarily to edit Meta Description. However, Yoast SEO Plugin, by default, shows up Title and Meta Description. So I have two MD and I can't switch off Yoast SEO Plugin -- no tick box to switch off the MD.

I need your advice. What do I do? I want to kill Yoast SEO Plugin's MD but I don't know how. I want to keep using SEO Ultimate but -- damn! -- I can't do it because of this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw this into your functions.php:

```
function clear_yoast_metadesc( $metadesc ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'clear_yoast_metadesc', 99, 1 );
```

If you set the `$metadesc` to empty like that, it won't be echoed. BTW, bulk editing is very hard on my to-do list, so you would be able to switch back completely :)